# Filtrar datos por Id en ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un portal de empleo, el cual en la vista principal, me muestra todas las ofertas condicionadas por otra tabla (ya que es un currículum del usuario).

Necesito que al postular una oferta, esta no se muestre nuevamente en la vista principal, dejo controlador:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.OfPostUsr_ID = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindByName(User.Identity.Name).Email;
    ViewBag.OfPostOf_ID = new SelectList(db.OfertaLaboral, "Of_ID", "Of_Titulo");

    var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    var lista2 = (from u in db.OfertaLaboral
                  from a in db.DatosUsuario
                  from d in db.OfertaPostulante
                  where u.Of_Edu == a.Educ_Sup
                  where u.Of_Mov == a.Mov_Red
                  where u.Of_Jornada == a.Jorn_Comp
                  where u.Of_Estado == a.Tipo_trabajo
                  where a.DatosUser_ID == userID

                  orderby u.Of_FechaIn descending
                  select u);

    ViewBag.ListaCondicion = lista2.ToList();
    return View();
}
```

Esto me muestra todas las ofertas del sistema, el cual lo guarda en el registro de postulación del usuario. ¿Como lo puedo hacer?

Comment: ¿es decir que llevas datos repetidos en `ViewBag.OfPostOf_ID` y en `lista2`?

Comment: El primero da igual, ya que solo ocupo la variable para mostrar las ofertas, aunque se que debo eliminarlo, pero si, está repetido. La idea es que el usuario no postule a una oferta ya postulada, y como lo tengo ahora, muestra todas las ofertas... alguna idea de como realizarlo? Gracias por responder :D